# How to open a device file at path: /dev/targetdev?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a homework about writing a module in linux kernel. I have declared 2 functions for character driver (open and read). And i can run normally with "sudo cat" command.
But when i used user_test.c file to test this module, it doesn't work. It can't open device file at "/dev/targetdev". (In my case, targetdev = "vchar_dev").
Please help me to fix it.
Thanks!

```c
//code in module file
static int vchar_driver_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *flip){
 printk("Open successfully\n");
 return 0;
}

//code in user_test.c
#define DEVICE_NODE "/dev/vchar_dev"


int open_chardev() {
    int fd = open(DEVICE_NODE, O_RDWR);
    if(fd < 0) {
        printf("Can not open the device file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: `O_RDWR` maybe try read only? Please show more code then just two small functions snippets. How do you detect that `It can't open device`? Please be specific. Does the `fd` returned by `open` call is lower then zero? Why do you mention `/dev/targetdev` while you open `/dev/vchar_dev`?

Comment: `O_RDWR` as the name suggests is `O_ReaD WRite`

Comment: i use **O_RDWR** because i just want to read only. **It can't open device** It means that "can't open device file at "dev/vchar_dev". When i use open_chardev(), fd return lower than 0. And in my case, path is "dev/vchar_dev". Sorry about my english.

Comment: @LinhHa O_RDWR is read AND write. Use O_RDONLY

Comment: @klutt i tried but the same result

Comment: You should check the value of `errno` (or use `perror` or `strerror`) for more information about why `open()` failed.

Comment: You're writing a module for a custom character device, right? Show the full code of the module, otherwise it's impossible to say what's wrong.

Comment: might sound stupid but you use "sudo cat" , meaning you require specific rigths to access this file. Do you run your program with the same user/rights ?
you might require some access right adjustement on your file to allow regular user to open it.

Comment: Oh, i've discovered my error. I ran my C program with normal rights, so i can't open file at "dev/vchar_dev". I tried to add "sudo" in command line and it works normally. Is that right way?

Comment: a little bit late maybe but it will be better to create a specific group and provide it read access to this device. Then, you will be able to give access to any user that runs you program as soon as you place them in that group.
If your device is created upon connection thru udev, make a search for udev rules to find how to dynamically assign the correct access rights